# What LEGO set does this yellow and lime green vehicle belong to?

Tags: set-identification, vehicle

This appears to be a helicopter or submarine of some sort. It is lime green and yellow with luminous yellow trimmings. It has cables and elastic parts with yellow cylinders. I thought it may be LEGO galaxy squad or Alien Conquest but I couldn't find it. The remaining parts are mixed in the LEGO bin and I need to figure out what it is to use the instructions to find them. Any clues would be much appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

It is part of [Toxikita's Toxic Meltdown (70163)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70163-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from [Ultra Agents](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=815)

[image]